# Frequency filtering in the frequency domain vs. time domain

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, frequency-domain, time-domain

As a DSP newbie, I've stumbled into doing band pass filtering (of pre-recorded IQ data) in the frequency domain - which allows brick wall filtering (I'm just setting the IQ values of each consecutive FFT 'batch' outside my frequency band of interest to zero and it seems to work a treat for what I've done so far). Doing filtering, e.g. a FIR, in the time domain seems to need many taps, a convolution function, and still not be as 'clean' as a brickwall filter. So, why/when is time domain frequency filtering the preferred way of doing it? Real time benefits? Works better with a low bandwidth SDR if subsequently transmitting? I should say that all my DSPing is being done in MatLab with no signal processing or other toolboxes - so I don't have access to FIR filter or convolution functions. If I want them, I have to write them or find them on-line somewhere - which I don't mind doing, if there's a good reason.

Comment: That's not brick-wall filtering. It's actually a sinc-shaped filterbank and has terrible sidelobes. You just sample the spectrum just so that you hit the zeros of the side lobes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins)

Comment: And as detailed further here as well: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31905/difference-between-frequency-sampling-and-windowing-method/31909#31909